# release android app updates and not not push auto updates

Tags: android

This is a repeated question as i have not got answer . Hope someone will look at this  and answer .

I have an android application which has number of downloads . I want to update the app with some major fixes and updates . Because of this update, end user may get failed authentication and need to reenter his credentials which I dont like. At the same time i want keep same package name to keep downloads and app reputation on playstore.

So how can i achive these
1.update android app on playstore which will not push automatic updates even if end user turn-on autoupdate in settings .

Previous app downloads and userfeedback should be there
So this way old users still continue using old version and any new users who download app from playstore will enjoy new app .

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this helps in your case but if you require an extra permission (from the previous version) the app will not auto update. Asking for an extra permission (something very simple and non-intrusive) could be a way for you to not autoupdate.

Comment: so if I add an additional  permission in manifest app will not auto update even if the end user turn-on auto update for  the same app?. Please confirm if this work then this is an answer .   And i would like to ask you why dont you post it as an answer instead of comment  (: . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you mentioned keeping a package name and stuff... Changing that should never be an option. The user could have ten of the same app, all with different features because your updates are all packaged separately. There isn't really a way to stop Google Play from auto updating apps, the users may just have to deal with reentering credentials. Since there isn't a way around this, you could simply apologize to the user. Example:
When the user logs in, save a boolean called something like, "wasLoggedIn". Then, on your login/startup page check if that is true. If it is, display a dialog such as, "Sorry for the inconvenience, you have been logged out due to an error." This will make the user a little more comfortable logging in again.

Comment: Yeah that is an issue  asking users to reenter login details and save  it .  Yes of course we can show them a sorry  message but  i need some sort of solution to avoid it

Comment: Yes, but you should never add a useless permission just to avoid updates. Its very sloppy and lazy, you should try to find a solution for saving the encrypted credentials then log them back in automatically.